# Edit clicked action

Tags: swift, onclick, uitextfield

I have some problem with clicked function on UITextField. I had implemented datepicker like in this example: http://blog.apoorvmote.com/change-textfield-input-to-datepicker/

and I have problem with clicked action. I had add 3 field. Only one field shows datepicker by pressing it. And I need to click twice on my UITextfield to show datepicker. What I did wrong and how fix it? I want to show datepicker on single click of UITextfeild.

Code:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RegisterViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    txtBirthday.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Comment: Please show some code, then only we can point out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the step while setting the action. In below step Event should be set as Editing Did Begin

Again add textfield as action & make sure to set “Event” to “Editing Did Begin”

[image]

Alternatively you can can the implementation to below one:

Set a tag to your dateTextField to say 10. You can do that in storyboard itself. Remove the action event from the textfield.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if(textField.tag == 10) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        textField.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RegisterViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }      
    return true;
 }
```